# Getting 404 on Ajax Request in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, spring-mvc, authentication

I am trying to make a simple login form. In which I am using Spring MVC and I have created a simple class for APIResponseModel(This class contains three variables and there getters and setters that are Status, Message, HTTPStatus) When I am filling the credentials and click on submit I am getting ajax response as 404 but when I checked the same in Controller it returns `{"status":"200","message":"Login Success!!","data":Admin}` for the same I am getting 404 as status in Ajax response. attaching the code here if you can please help me and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public APIResponseModel getLoginPage(@ModelAttribute("loginUser")UserDTO userDto, HttpSession session) {
        APIResponseModel apiResponseModel = new Utils().getDefaultApiResponse();
        logger.info("USER DTO :" + userDto.toString());
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            userService = new UserServiceImpl();
            UserModel userModel = userService.validateLogin(userDto,null, errorList);
            if(errorList.isEmpty()) {
                apiResponseModel.setMessage("Login Success!!");
                apiResponseModel.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                if(userModel.getRole() == Constants.UserRole.ADMIN) {
                    apiResponseModel.setData("Admin");
                }else if(userModel.getRole() == Constants.UserRole.STORE_MANAGER) {
                    apiResponseModel.setData("StoreOwner");
                }else {
                    apiResponseModel.setData("landing");
                }
                session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", userModel);
            }else {
                apiResponseModel.setMessage(errorList.isEmpty() ? "Invalid Credientials !!" : errorList.toString());
            }
            
        }catch(Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Exception occured at : " + exe.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        logger.info(apiResponseModel);
        return apiResponseModel;
    }
```

**Validate login JS Function**

```
function processLogin(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let formData = new FormData();
    console.log($("#email").val()); 
    console.log($("#password").val());
    //formData.append("key" , Value ) ; 
    formData.append("email", $("#email").val());
    formData.append("password" , $("#password").val()); 
    
    var obj = new MasterAjax();
    obj.requestType = "POST";
    obj.url = "login";
    obj.data = formData;
    obj.contentType = false;
    obj.requestData(function(responseData){
        console.log("RESPONSE DATA :::::::"+responseData);
        console.log(responseData.status);
        console.log(responseData.message);
        console.log(responseData.data);
        if(responseData.status == "OK"||responseData.status == "ok"){
            alert("success");
        }else{
            alert("Login failed");
        }
    }); 
}
```

**MasterAjax class**

```
class MasterAjax{
    constructor(){
        this.requestType = null;
        this.url = null;
        this.timeout = 100000;
        this.enctype =  null;
        this.data = null;
        this.processData = null;
        this.contentType = null;
        this.responseData = null;
        this.responseStatus = null;
        this.responseStatusCode = null;
    }
    
    requestData(callBack){
        
        var parameterError=false;
        if(null == this.requestType){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: Request Type can't be null");
        }    
        if(null === this.url || undefined === this.url || "undefined" === this.url){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: URL can't be null");
        }  
        if(null == this.data || this.data.length <= 0){
            //console.log("Warning: Data is null");
        }
        if(parameterError === false){
            /*toggleSpinnerOn();  */
            $.ajax({
                type : this.requestType,
                enctype : this.enctype,
                processData : this.processData, 
                contentType : this.contentType, 
                url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
                data: this.data,
                timeout : this.timeout,
                success : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();*/
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus);
                },
                error : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();  */
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus); 
                }
            }); 
        }
        //return this.responseData;
    }
    
}
```

**LoginForm**

```
<form class="page" name="loginForm">
 <input class="email" id="email" path="email"  type='text' align="center" placeholder="Username / Email" />
  <input class="pass" id="password" path="password" type='password' align="center" placeholder="Password" />
  <button class="submit" onclick="processLogin(event)">Sign in</button>
  <p class="forgot" align="center"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed `@ResponseBody` to add at the controller that's why it does not send the response on call.